# Question about Hilbert's axiom for the postive fragment of classical logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, nonclassical-logic

In his axiomization of the positive fragment of Classical Logic, Hilbert included the axiom

$(B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow [(C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)]$

along with the usual conjunction and disjunction axioms, Weakening and Self Distribution. All of those are good. But this monster is about the most opaque axiom I have seen. It has tantalizing hints of Pierce's Law $((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A$ in it, and clearly a variant of it can be obtained using Pierce's Law and Weakening. It is also used in his axiomization of the implication fragment of Classical Logic. If I could extract Pierce's Law, I could go to town. I can get a strong version of Chain, the Extended Law of Excluded Middle, and all of the distribution laws from Pierce's Law.

But this thing, I haven't gotten anything out of it. The best that I have gotten is $((A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)$ which doesn't seem to go anywhere. Nor, given everything else, have I been able to prove this axiom. I don't even have a name for it. The equivalence of $A \rightarrow B$ with ${\neg}A \lor B$ is not available in the positive fragment of Classical Logic since negation is not available. Additionally, since it also in the implication fragment, it must be intended to obtain some set of implication theses, neither disjunction, nor conjunction are available there. So, Hilbert must have intended the other implication axioms to be used which are just Weakening and Self Distribution. There is no clue as to what he expected to get out of it (unlike Pierce's Law where Pierce explicitly said it was to get the Law of Excluded Middle -- which, in restricted systems, it does not do, but does do so much else).

I have tried using Self Distribution, Importation, Permutation, Assertion, all sorts of substitutions, etc., but haven't a bit of luck in either proving it or using it. I have verified that it satisfies a truth table model to make sure that it has been transcribed correctly. Nor have I found anything on the web. I found this is in the book "Propositional Logics" 3rd ed. by Richard L. Epstein, pages 83 and 85, questions pages 85-86. He only refers to it in a single question, which is whether or not it can be replaced by Pierce's law for the implication fragment, but then he also says to prove that adding Pierce's Law is necessary for that axiomization is strongly complete. Those questions together suggest that it cannot be replaced by Pierce's Law.

Does anyone have a clue as to how to either prove this monster, or how to use it in a Hilbert / Frege type of system (which, of course, what he would have been using)? What in the world is this axiom intended to do? I do not believe that Hilbert put in there just to confound everyone in the future.

Thanks.

Edit: With a bit of fiddling, I see a possible path forward. What follows is not a formal proof of anything, but shows a possible direction with a bit of hand waving. Please overlook any mismatched parentheses here or there. Those are just typos, I tried to avoid them, but pasting things back and forth may have caused a slip.

So, start with the original equation.

$(B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow [(C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)]$

Now, as a starting point, make the substitution $B \leftarrow A$

$(A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow [(C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (((A \rightarrow C) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)]$

We know that we have $A \rightarrow A$ by using Ax 1 and Ax 2, so use detachment (Rl 1).

$(C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (((A \rightarrow C) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)$

Now use Self Distribution (Ax 2).

$((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow C) \rightarrow A)) \rightarrow ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)$

Just go mad with Self Distribution (the nested occurrences will make for a very painful proof, but should work).

$((((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)) \rightarrow ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)$

This is a mess, so lets define a local constant $R := (C \rightarrow A)$

$[((R \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow A)] \rightarrow (R \rightarrow A)$

This is starting to look familiar, so lets define a couple of additional constants $X := (R \rightarrow A)$ and $Y := (R \rightarrow C)$

$[(X \rightarrow Y) \rightarrow X] \rightarrow X$

This is clearly Pierce's Law. The problem is that $X$ and $Y$ are expressions. But, using a model checking tool, I checked that

$X = ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A) \leftrightarrow A$
$Y = ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow C) \leftrightarrow C$

```
   | (C    ->     A)  | -> |  A  |
   +------------------+----+-----+
   |  F     T     F   | F  |  F  |
   |                  |    |     |
   |  T     F     F   | T  |  F  |
   |                  |    |     |
   |  F     T     T   | T  |  T  |
   |                  |    |     |
   |  T     T     T   | T  |  T  |
   +------------------+----+-----+

   | (C    ->     A)  | -> |  C  |
   +------------------+----+-----+
   |  F     T     F   | F  |  F  |
   |                  |    |     |
   |  T     F     F   | T  |  T  |
   |                  |    |     |
   |  F     T     T   | F  |  F  |
   |                  |    |     |
   |  T     T     T   | T  |  T  |
   +------------------+----+-----+
```

It is almost true for $A$, but is true for $C$. We can easily show one direction.

$A \rightarrow ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A)$

$C \rightarrow ((C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow C)$

If we can get a proof in the other direction for at least $C$, then we have equivalence, and can substitute  $Y \leftarrow C$ giving

$[(X \rightarrow C) \rightarrow X] \rightarrow X$

which is just Pierce's Law with arbitrary $C$, but flawed for $A$. I don't have an immediate solution for that, but at least it is a direction to examine.

This is close. It is possible that the difference between $A$ doesn't actually make a difference or that something else can be done. Time to go to bed and let my subconscious work on it.

Edit 2: By request, here are images of the four pages in Epstein's book which are relevant.

[image: Page 83]
[image: Page 84]
[image: Page 85]
[image: Page 86]

Comment: Could you share the relevant parts of Epstein's book (3rd edition)?

Comment: Done. Pages 83-86.

Comment: Thank you. I greatly appreciate your contribution. I hope this will benefit other fellows, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am really quite busy right now, but I do happen to know the solution, so this is going to be a "drive-by" proof. Apologies if something won't make sense, or if I make a serious typo, but I probably won't have time to correct/clarify it until next week.*

First, observe that $((a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a) \rightarrow (a \rightarrow a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a$ is an intuitionistic tautology, so you can somehow derive it from the first two axioms. I would just translate a proof from another system.

Now, we have:

- **1** $((a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a) \rightarrow (a \rightarrow a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a$ [derivable from ax1,ax2]
- **2** $x \rightarrow x$ [derivable from ax1,ax2]
- **3** $(x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow (y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow ((x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow x) \rightarrow x$ [instance of ax3]
- **4** $(y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow ((x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow x) \rightarrow x$ [MP 2,3]
- **5** $((y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow ((x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow x) \rightarrow x) \rightarrow ((y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow ((x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow x))
     \rightarrow ((y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow x)$ [instance of ax2]
- **6** $(y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow ((x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow x))
     \rightarrow ((y \rightarrow x) \rightarrow x$ [MP4,5]
- **7** $((a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a) \rightarrow ((a \rightarrow (a \rightarrow b)) \rightarrow a))
     \rightarrow (((a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a) \rightarrow a$ [sub $x:=a, y:=a\rightarrow b$ in 6]
- **8** $((a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a) \rightarrow a$ [MP1,7]

This gives you Peirce's law, so you can go to town!

Comment: Thank you. I formalized that and it worked! (1) follows directly from Contraction and Suffixing, so no problem. Do you know if this is the only use of this axiom? I really dislike those axioms from a century ago which are "clever" and like really, really bad programming. Lots of unnecessary complexity instead of simple, straight forward axioms. The can be nightmare until you figure out the "trick". We know that Pierce used his to get excluded middle. I wonder if that is what Hilbert was trying to do? In restricted systems, I use it to get Chain (p -> q) v (q -> p) giving the distribution laws.

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney: I understand your frustration with this axiom. One way to think about it is that it's a way of writing $((B \vee C) \rightarrow A) \wedge (\neg B \vee C) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A$, which is a fairly legible, if too verbose classical principle. From this perspective, it seems like it'd probably be fairly easy to use in many situations by setting $C$ to $A$. (although this is not the strategy I used to obtain Peirce's law).

Comment: Thank you, that is a good insight into this axiom. Other than Pierce's Law, do you know of anything else that follows from it? In an implication only system or a positive only system, this interpretation doesn't make much sense since there is no intention to define negation in either system. So you won't have excluded middle or absurdity. I don't normally work with axioms like this, I usually use a saner set of axioms. A dozen axioms is a fair price to pay for readability and understanding the intent. But, I am trying to work my through a bunch of these to understand how to use them.